# How can i do target on PopupPanel widget and it's children widget?

Tags: gwt

I am using PopupPanel in GWT for example(popup) and one widget button for example(B1) add in this popup.When i target my mouse pointer on label For Example(lbl) then popup is show causing  onMouseEnter and this popup hide when mouse pointer away from this lbl but i can not target this popup add button B1 because of mouse pointer away from this lbl popup hide. So my question is that how can i target popup widget and its children widget for enent?

i use popup.isModal onMouseLeave but is not working.

Thanks 
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire widget in the popup with a FocusPanel.